# how do I align a view on top of 1 of 2 views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Click on image, replace with relativelayout as shown below.  This bottom section should be below the listview.  Problem is I dont see the listview in the design preview of my IDE.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomSection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:onClick="switch"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomSection" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: share your layout xml and what you have tried options

Comment: Take a FrameLayout as listview footer and dynamically add your layout according to your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

In you xml vertical LinearLayout as parent layout and A,B and ListView as child,given weight to ListView so it can adjust height even if no A or B visible and in case of shown A or B you have to implement on click of both in activity like when A show and click show B and hide A and vise versa.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible">

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">

    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the two linearlayouts in another linearlayout, And use parent linearlayout for reference in Listview.

Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.tempproj.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lay2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/container" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So your Listview will be on top of container LinearLayout, regardless of which linearlayout is visible inside that. Hope it helps.